# Apache Ignite Caching and PeerClassLoading

Tags: ignite

**1. Is it possible to put non-POJO class instances as the value of a cache?**

For example, I have a QueryThread class which is a subclass of java.lang.Thread and I am trying to put this instance in a cache. It looks like the put operation is failing because this cache is always empty.

Consider the following class:

```
public class QueryThread extends Thread {

private IgniteCache<?, ?> cache;
private String queryId;
private String query;
private long timeIntervalinMillis;
private volatile boolean running = false;

public QueryThread(IgniteCache<?, ?> dataCache, String queryId, String query, long timeIntervalinMillis) {
    this.queryId = queryId;
    this.cache = dataCache;
    this.query = query;
    this.timeIntervalinMillis = timeIntervalinMillis;
}

public void exec() throws Throwable {
    SqlFieldsQuery qry = new SqlFieldsQuery(query, false);
    while (running) {
        List<List<?>> queryResult = cache.query(qry).getAll();
        for (List<?> list : queryResult) {
            System.out.println("result : "+list);
        }
        System.out.println("..... ");
        Thread.sleep(timeIntervalinMillis);
    }
}
}
```

This class is not a POJO. How do I store an instance of this class in the cache?
I tried implementing Serializable (didn't help).
I need to be able to do this:

```
queryCache.put(queryId, queryThread);
```

Next I tried broadcasting the class using the IgniteCallable interface. But my class takes multiple arguments in the constructor. I feel PeerClassLoading is easy if the class takes a no-arg constructor:

```
 IgniteCompute compute = ignite.compute(ignite.cluster().forServers());
     compute.broadcast(new IgniteCallable<MyServiceImpl>() {

        @Override
        public MyServiceImpl call() throws Exception {
            MyServiceImpl myService = new MyServiceImpl();
            return myService;
        }

    });
```

**2. How do I do PeerClassLoading in the case of a class with multi-arg constructor?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's restricted to put Thread instances to the cache, Thread instance cannot be serialized due to call to Native Methods. Thats why you always get empty value.
2. PeerClassLoading is a special distributed ClassLoader in Ignite for inter-node byte-code exchange. So, it's only about sharing classes between nodes. It doesn't make sense how many arguments in constructor class have.
   But, on the other hand, object, that you created, will be serialised and sent to other nodes and for deserialisation it will need a default(non-arg) constructor.

Comment: Regarding Point#2 -> 
1. Was my way of doing PeerClassLoading the right way to do(as shown in the example)?

Comment: 2. Is there any other way I can do PeerClassLoading if my constructor has multiple args?

Comment: It's always better to create a class that implements IgniteCallable and apply it as argument to broadcast because Java always take an outer class in addition to anonymous class on serialization

Comment: 2. As I said earlier, PeerClassLoading is about classes, but you sending an instance of its class. You can use classes with any constructors, but, in addition, you need to add a default constructor for serialization.

Comment: Can I send a class instead of an instance of the class? How can I do it? Can you give me some code example? Or is there some example code I can refer to in the source code?

Comment: Why do you think that you need to send class instead of instance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151872/discussion-between-james-isaac-and-evgenii-zhuravlev).